# SQL Query for multiple matches on same column of associated table

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two tables, foos and bars. bars belong to foos, and foos have multiple bars (via ActiveRecord). I want to find a foo which has bars of exactly (and only) a given list of bar names.

E.g. (please excuse any pseudocode)

```
bars_list = ["A", "B"]
foo = find_foo(bars_list)
foo.bars.map(&:name) = ["A", "B"]
```

Find foo doesn't necessarily need to be strictly a function. It can be an SQL query to return matching foo ids or very efficient ActiveRecord functions. Thanks!

Comment: I used an SQL query with an INNER JOIN using WHERE EXISTS ...bar.name = ?... AND EXISTS ... bar.name = ? ... But this did not get any matches for foos where both bar.name="A" and bar.name="B" existed. It did interestingly, return all correct foos if I used EXISTS ... OR EXISTS... but I need them to both exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to filter the result set for the desired number of matching bar records:

```
SELECT foos.*
FROM foos
JOIN bars ON bars.foo_id = foos.id
WHERE bars.name IN ('bar1', 'bar2')
GROUP BY foos.id, foos.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If you have three names, check for `COUNT(*) = 3` and so on.